# Send an automatic BCC from a specific account in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have coded a VBA macro to send a BCC when I send an email. Everything is working great but now there are 2 accounts in Outlook.

I only want the BCC to be sent from a particular account and not any of the others.

How can I do that?

I have tried using `Account.DisplayName` but it does not work. I do not think I am referencing things properly.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Steve! I think it would be helpful if you could provide us with the code you already have. Just [edit] your post, insert it, and format it by pressing `Ctrl-K` for the code. Also note that I've removed your signature according to the [FAQ#signatures]. Cheers!